# Adding forms to flowlayoutpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, layoutpanels

I have an app that I need to be able to add child forms to a Main form.  I can add the child forms to the main form at runtime easy enough, but when I resize the main form, the child forms do not resize accordingly.

I was wondering if adding the child forms to a flowlayoutpanel would help with resizing or should I just subscribe to the main forms "resize" event and resize the child forms accordingly.

Comment: Resizing of child controls is not aspect of flowlayoutpanel behaviour. For example, Windows Explorer does not resize your file icons, when you resize the window. For management of resizing of child controls its better to use TablelayoutPanel

Comment: By "child forms" and "main form", it sounds like you have an **MDI application**. In that case, you can't arrange the forms into either a FlowLayoutPanel or a TableLayoutPanel. Actually, you can't do that in *any* case. You need to use a Panel or some other control, rather than a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select a proper layoutPanel control from TablelayoutPanel, FlowlayoutPanel or SplitContainer as per your requirement. The description you have given is not enough to recommend a proper one for you.

Regardless of the layout panel, control resizing won't happen automatically. You have to set the [Dock property to Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle.aspx), in order to resize your child controls controls. Again not sure what you mean by child controls? If they are UserControls they may work fine.